# Which domain to use for sql server developer

Tags: sql-server, license

My current company does not have a QA domain in a hosting data enter where all the data bases are located . I want to know that in order to use developer editions of sql server, should I be using it in a domain which is different from production servers ? Or can I name the QA servers with a different naming convention and still use them in the same domain where prod is present? We have 3 data centers and in all the 3, the QA servers are in the same domain as prod . Is this ok ?

I noticed that my current client does have a QA.xx domain, but there are no servers hosted in it. Please advice which is the way to go to test newer configurations and setups because I want to take advantage of the developer editions of sql server

Answer (score 4):

The Dev license is not about where, but rather how the installation is used.  If you are not using it for Production, its fine.    Separating out by domain is great, but not required.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier we want to test some proof of concept configurations involving AAG's and did not want to waste enterprise license until the poc was tested

Comment: @user2923332, as long as the use is not production, you can test AGs anywhere using DE.